# How to use find command with user input?

Tags: unix, shell

Code:

```
echo "Enter the file name"

read fname

find / -name `$fname` -print
```

Issue: getting error  message 'Command not found'

```
Enter the file to searched \n

myfile

Check01.sh: line 4: myfile: command not found
```

I want to search the file name entered by the user at the command prompt.

What is the correct syntax or is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: Your output does not match your script. Be accurate.

Comment: I formatted your code for you, which reveals the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using backticks ('`'), rather than quotation marks.

Your shell is trying to execute the input (`myfile`) and use this as the input to the `find` command.

Try this instead:

```
echo "Enter the file name:";
read fname;
find / -name "$fname" -print
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
find . -xdev -iname "*$1*"
```

I call it `qfind` (for quick find).

Use it like this:

```
qfind foo
```

Comment: correct me if am wrong this will search for the file  in the current directory only ?

Comment: @Amith yes, you are wrong. This will also search recursively all directories below the current one.